# Store regression models in dataframe

Tags: r

I conduct a large number of regression analyses using `ols` and `cph` (different models, sensitivity analyses etc) which takes on my computer around two hours. Therefore, I would like to save these models so that I don't have to re-run the same analyses every time I want to work with them. The models all have very structured names, so I can create a list of names as follows:

```
model.names <- list()[grep("^im", ls())
```

But how can I use this to save those models? Could they be placed into a data frame?

Comment: You can save the models in a list.

Comment: `L <- lapply(model.names, FUN=get)` or short `L <- mget(model.names)` Can you show us how you generate the models? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you! That works very well!

Comment: This could be helpful http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1e8a3-b5-w

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for save()

save writes an external representation of R objects to the specified file. The objects can be read back from the file at a later date by using the function load or attach (or data in some cases).

Comment: Save does work - the problem was to get the list in a way that it works. `L <- lapply(model.names, FUN=get)` dies the trick!